# r how to keep print method for custom class

Tags: r, class, printing

i have defined a method for printing a vector with the class test:

```
print.test <- function(x,  ...) {
    x <- formatC(
        as.numeric(x),
        format = "f",
        big.mark = ".",
        decimal.mark = ",",
        digits = 1
        )
    x[x == "NA"] <- "-"
    x[x == "NaN"] <- "-"
    print.default(x)
}
```

which works fine for the following

```
a <- c(1000.11, 2000.22, 3000.33)
class(a) <- c("test", class(a))
print(a)
[1] "1.000,11" "2.000,22" "3.000,33"
```

this also works:

```
round(a)
[1] "1.000,0" "2.000,0" "3.000,0"
```

this does not:

```
median(a)
[1] 2000.22
class(median(a))
[1] "numeric"
```

now my question is: do i need to write a custom method for this class to use median e.g. and if so what would it look like or is there another way (as i simply would like this class to print the data in a certain format)?

Comment: You'd need to define methods for `sort` and `mean` since they strip the class attribute and as a result, so does `median`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `median.default` returns an object of class `numeric` therefore autoprinting of the returned object does not call your custom `print` method.
The following will do so.

```
median.test <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE, ...){
    y <- NextMethod(x, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
    class(y) <- c("test", class(y))
    y
}

median(a)
#[1] "2.000,2"
```

As for the handling of `NA` values, I will first define another method for a base R function. It is not strictly needed but save some code lines if objects of class `test` are used frequently.

```
c.test <- function(x, ...){
    y <- NextMethod(x, ...)
    class(y) <- c("test", class(y))
    y
}


b <- c(a, NA)
class(b)
#[1] "test"    "numeric"

median(b)
#[1] "-"

median(b, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] "2.000,2"
```

**EDIT.**

The following defines a generic function `wMedian`, a default method and a method for objects of class `"currency"`, as requested by the OP in a comment.

Note that there must be a method `print.currency`, which I don't redefine since it's exactly the same as `print.test` above.  As for the other methods, I have made them simpler with the help of a new function, `as.currency`.

```
median.currency <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE, ...){
  y <- NextMethod(x, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  as.currency(y)
}

c.currency <- function(x, ...){
  y <- NextMethod(x, ...)
  as.currency(y)
}

as.currency <- function(x){
  class(x) <- c("currency", class(x))
  x
}

wMedian <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("wMedian")
wMedian.default <- function(x, ...){
    matrixStats::weightedMedian(x, ...)
}

wMedian.currency <- function(x, w = NULL, idxs = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, interpolate = is.null(ties), ties = NULL, ...) {
  y <- NextMethod(x, w = w, idxs = idxs, na.rm = na.rm, interpolate = interpolate, ties = ties, ... ) 
  as.currency(y)
}


set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10)
wMedian(x, w = (1:10)/10)
#[1] 0.4084684
wMedian(as.currency(x), w = (1:10)/10)
#[1] "0,4"
```

Comment: The method for `<-` seems unnecessary and wrong. The first argument of `<-` is the symbol that the second argument is assigned into. Also, `<-` is not an S3 generic.

Comment: @Roland You are right. My mistake comes from having defined both `<-.test` and `c.test`, which is generic, and tested `c(a, NA)`. It obviously worked, with or without `<-.test`. Thanks for noticing this.

Comment: im now trying to implement the same procedure for weightedMedian from the matrixStats package. somehow the same approach does not quite work here. any ideas?

weightedMedian.currency <-
  function(x,
           w = NULL,
           idxs = NULL,
           na.rm = FALSE,
           interpolate = is.null(ties),
           ties = NULL,
           ...) {
    y <- NextMethod(
      x,
      w = NULL,
      idxs = NULL,
      na.rm = FALSE,
      interpolate = is.null(ties),
      ties = NULL,
      ...
    )
    class(y) <- c("currency", class(y))
    y
  }

Comment: @jaydee Like you coded it it doesn't work because `weightedMedian` is not generic. `isGeneric("weightedMedian")` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thx, i was guessing that the probleme involves something like this. any ideas on how i can still get this to work, in order to keep the additional class "currency" i added to my vector?

Comment: @jaydee See if this is it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thx! yes you are right, weightedMedian from matrixStats is non-generic. Any ideas how to keep the classes of "a" for weightedMedain(x=a, w=b)?

Comment: @jaydee The easier way I'm seeing is to call `wMedian` defined in the answer. Alternatively, you could write a wrapper for `weightedMedian` similar to `wMedian.default`: call `y <- weightedMedian(a, b)` and return `as.currency(y)`.